# using regexp_filters in sphinx index

Tags: regex, sphinx

I am trying to use regexp_filter to replace specific word suffixes as I am finding the stem_en and lemmatizer to throw unexpected results.

I tried

```
regexp_filter = (.*)(graphical|graphic|graph) => \1graphy
```

But for some reason a search for 'Biography' does not match 'Biographical'

I checked in regex101 that my regex works:

https://regex101.com/r/zM9jY5/1

at least so far as finding the pattern and groups

and I checked in sphinx that a simple/direct replacement

```
regexp_filter = Biographical => Biography
```

works.

So clearly the regex pattern matches and clearly the regexp_filter replacement works. Somehow using

```
(.*)(graphical|graphic|graph) => \1graphy
```

is not recognizing either the groups or the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, capturing any number of characters other than a newline (with `.*`) and capturing them to just restore them later in the replacement makes little sense.

You can just use

```
graphical|graphic|graph
```

And replace with `graphy`.

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK1xZ6/1)

If you *DO NOT* want to match whole words `graphic` and `graph`, you can use

```
graphical|\bgraphic\b|\bgraph\b
```

Comment: Actually I  used backreferences successfully already in other regex_p. I will try just doing graphical|graphic|graph, that did not work with wordforms but you are correct I think that regex_p should handle it fine. I just need to modify it so it does NOT modify the word graph or graphic.

Comment: Do you mean you DO NOT want to match whole words `graphic` and `graph`? Use `graphical|\bgraphic\b|\bgraph\b`.

Comment: To be clear a backreference is within the regular expression itself (ie back-referencing a match within the same expression) - the linked page is to the regular expression syntax, NOT hte replacement syntax. **A \1 on the replacement side, is perfectly fine**.  Capturing regular expressions to use for replacements is supported by re2 and sphinx. (but I agree capturing .* makes no sense)

Comment: @barryhunter: Thank you for clarifying. I updated the answer and included the latest comment to the answer  body.

Comment: @barryhunter Thanks, not trying to diverge into a regex q but in fact graphical|!\bgraph\b would match graphical and NOT match the whole word graph. To match photograph and not graph i need to do !\bgraph\b|graph. It appears however regexp_filter in combination with wordforms is a good way to extend the functionality of it thank you.

Comment: I think you need to read up on assertions, you might have them backwards